# Using mysql instead of redis to share context for clients hitting multiple instances

Tags: mysql, node.js, redis, socket.io

Okay , i went through a few posts regarding scalabality of nodejs/socket.io . And in all cases i found out that apart from using load balancers , it is recommended to use redis for key:value storage in order to share context for clients hitting multiple instances . My question is , of course we can use database systems like mysql (and i want to) , but what are the advantages of using redis ?

Answer (score 3):

Using MySQL is fine for your business critical data when you need [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties to be guaranteed. However there are other kinds of data, like sessions or counters, which would benefit from fast read/write access and that's where redis excel. Moreover it goes beyond simple K/V store functionality and provides advanced [data structures](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) and [pub-sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) messaging system that can help you to solve many problems with elegant and very fast way.